# Split a text file by its entries

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to analyze an enormous text file (1.6GB), whose data lines look like this:

```
20090118025859 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090118025900 -2.500000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090118025901 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
```

I don't even know how many lines there are. But I'm trying to split the file by date. The left number is a time stamp (these lines are from 2009, January 18th).
How can I split this file into pieces according to the date?

Everything I know would be to `grep file '20090118*' > data20090118.dat` , but there sure is a way to do all the dates at once, right?

The number of entries per date differ, so using `split` with a constant number won't work.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I think this question belongs to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: For counting the number of lines, use [wc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/wc.1.html): `wc -l file`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the file is sorted and the dates are always there, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir='./'    

while read line; do
    date="${line:0:8}"
    echo "$line" >> "$base_dir$date.txt"
done < "$1"
```

[Save it as `my_splitter`, make it executable by running `chmod +x my_splitter`, then call it like `./my_splitter input_file`]

It reads the input file line by line, extracts the date and uses that to append the lines with the same date to the same file.

`base_dir` is the target directory, and the files will be of the form `<date>.txt`. Note: existing files won't be overwritten, new lines would be appended due to the `>>` redirector, so better make sure the target directory doesn't contain any files of the form `<date>.txt`.

Comment: Instead of `$(echo "$line" | cut -b 1-8)` you can do `${line:0:8}`, which is shorter and more efficient. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations

Answer (score 1):

This could probably work for you:

```
awk '{d=substr($1, 1, 8); fn = "data" d ".dat"; print $0 >> fn}' hugefile
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use {x..y}, maybe for y, m, d cascading, shema:

```
for d in {18..19} ; do grep 200901$d datadata; echo; done 
20090118025859 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090118025900 -2.500000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090118025901 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000

20090119025859 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090119025900 -2.500000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
20090119025901 -2.400000 78.100000 1023.200000 0.000000
```